# Counteract joule-heating

Tags: heat, conductors, heat-protection

I've got a project where I have an intricate structure made of fine wire, through which a comparatively large current will be sent. Unfortunately, the conductor itself respons poorly to heat, and if the high current flows, the system fails. Is there a way to reduce or redirect the heat? I thought about using a high frequency current to use the skin effect. That way, if I coated the structure in a heat resistant material, the current would run through that instead of the structure. Unfortunately, this still doesn't work because mezals are great at conducting heat. So, I was wondering if it was possible to solve this problem at the root, as in not generating heat in the first place. If anyone knows how, please tell me. Thx.

Comment: Not sure what parameters we are free to change. Making the cross sectional area of the wire larger would be the obvious thing. I guess you can't do that? Cooling the wire might help (like with liquid nitrogen) because most wires have lower resistance at lower temperature. Even if you don't cool it, running it inside of a liquid (such as transformer oil) will help transfer the heat from the wire to the oil. Adding high velocity forced air convection may help remove heat from the wire more quickly. Changing wire alloy may help. Pure copper, pure silver and pure aluminum would be good candidates.

Comment: The other thing would be to reduce the amount of time that the high current flows. I have no idea what you are doing. But if you can send the current in a very brief pulse (e.g., 100ms), and then do whatever you need to do during the latter half of the 100ms pulse, then let the current return to zero, not much heating will occur.

Answer (score 2):

> thought about using a high frequency current to use the skin effec

Skin effect will make your current flow through *less* of the wire's cross-section, thereby increasing resistance, and thereby increasing heat – not only linearly, but quadratic. So, that's making things worse, quadratically with frequency. Don't do it.

> That way, if I coated the structure in a heat resistant material, the current would run through that instead of the structure.

You need that coating to be of higher conductivity than the core wire. That's indeed done – tinned or copper-clad wire is a thing. If the coating was of lower conductivity, it would be worse than just making your wire thicker by the same amount.

But you'd still be better of *without* the skin effect – obviously, you still get lower overall resistance when you don't use high frequency. The current through the coating and through the wire will be split according to the first-semester-first-class-first-hour current divider formula, anyways.

> So, I was wondering if it was possible to solve this problem at the root, as in not generating heat in the first place. If anyone knows how, please tell me

Use a superconducting material instead of your wire. No other options.

If you just want to *reduce* the amount of heat produced, thicker wires, or coating your wires with copper or silver and using the lowest frequency current possible will be the right solution.

Of course, avoiding to transport high currents through thin wires alltogether would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't improve the losses by increasing the frequency, it will have just the opposite effect. Aside from changing the material, geometry or conditions to get higher  conductivity there's not much you can do.

However if your goal is to transmit power through thin wires, it may be possible to increase the voltage and then decrease it again after it passes through.

For example, instead of sending 5V at 10A, you could send 50V at 1.2A and use an 80% efficient DC-DC converter to get 5V at 10A. The losses would be reduced by the square of the voltage ratio, ignoring the DC-DC losses. In this case the wire losses would be reduced to about 1/70 taking the DC-DC into account.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to reduce or **redirect** the heat?

You can "redirect" the heat using air flow, preferably forced air flow and/or chilled air flow.

You should consider exactly how the conductors respond poorly to heat. Do they soften, elongate, oxidize, break? You may be able to purchase conductors that are made from an alloy that performs better in your application.